# Setting a value of an attached property via Reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reflection, dependency-properties

I am able to obtain a property called ShowKeyboardCuesProperty which is an attached dependency property present in KeyboardNavigation class. It is an internal static DP with no backing CLR property.

```
(typeof(KeyboardNavigation).GetMember("ShowKeyboardCuesProperty", MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)[0] as FieldInfo)
```

I need to set this attached property on another element whose reference I can get easily. Let's refer to that element as DependencyObject d.

How can I call d.SetValue() and set the above attached property(from FieldInfo) to true?

Or is there any other way I can achieve the same?

Comment: Attached properties are strictly a feature of XAML. This is unrelated to Windows API programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FieldInfo fi = (typeof(KeyboardNavigation).GetMember("ShowKeyboardCuesProperty",
    MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)[0] as FieldInfo);

DependencyObject o = new Button();

DependencyProperty dp = fi.GetValue(o) as DependencyProperty;
bool value = (bool)o.GetValue(dp); //= false
o.SetValue(dp, true);
value = (bool)o.GetValue(dp); // = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.